# Why are five independent slip systems required for plasticity to occur at the macroscopic level?

Tags: material-science

According to the von Mises criteria, we often encounter that five independent slip system is required for plasticity to occur at macroscopic level. Can somebody give an explain briefly about this proof or argument?

Comment: Can you clarify why the explanation in [Wikipedia's von Mises yield criterion page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_yield_criterion) is not sufficient? That page explains why/when the yield criterion is expressed in terms of the traceless symmetric part of the $3\times 3$ Cauchy stress tensor, and the traceless symmetric part of any $3\times 3$ matrix has five independent components. Are you asking for a more detailed explanation of why/when the tracless symmetric part is sufficient?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I need better explanation in term of plasticity in general. You can look at this https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14786436308213843?journalCode=tphm19 , it states about volumetric strain to be dependent equation and six strain are independent. I need other people view on plasticity apart from just equation

Answer (score 1):

Since arbitrary deformation involves `6` strains, and if you have a constant volume which gives you `1` constraint, you end up with `6 - 1 = 5` independent strains. Now, analogous to needing `5` pieces of data to solve a simple system of equations with `5` unknown variables, you need exactly `5` slip systems to determined the `5` independent strains.

More mathematically, we have `6` different strains labeled as $\varepsilon_{ij}$, since $\varepsilon$ is a ***symmetric tensor*** that can be described by only:

$$
\tag{1}
\varepsilon_{11},~~\varepsilon_{12},~~\varepsilon_{13},~~\varepsilon_{22},~~\varepsilon_{23},~~\varepsilon_{33},
$$

and then we have the one constraint due to enforcing the volume to be constant:

\begin{eqnarray}
\tag{2}
\textrm{Tr}\left( \varepsilon \right) &=0, \\ \varepsilon_{11}+\varepsilon_{22}+\varepsilon_{33}&= 0.\tag{3}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: why above set of constraint is applicable to only dislocation slip not to twin. Twin also doesn't change volume.

Answer (score 0):

But what happens if we are considering the deformation of a single crystal? And there are a lot of papers showing that only one or two slip systems are activated in a grain.